# What is the macOS equivalent to Window's AppData folder?

Tags: macos, applications

I was originally looking for my Google Chrome profile because something went wrong and I need to delete it. In the process I realized that I don't know where applications in general are putting this kind of stuff.

Where is the typical place to go looking?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This kind of data is frequently stored in `~/Library/Application Support`.

User-specific settings are frequently stored in `~/Library/Preferences`

Your Chrome profile is located at `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`.

I recommend going on a little exploration of the ~/Library folder; there's a lot of useful stuff in there.

Comment: Note that in Lion the ~/Library folder is hidden in the finder by default. You can still go there by using the "Go to folder" functionality.

Comment: @Nathan, You missed out `~/Library/<application name>/`

Comment: Is there an environment variable for that?

Comment: Data shouldn't be saved to these `Preferences` folders without using Apple's API. According to Apple's File System Programming Guide linked by @Bachsau, "Contains the user’s preferences. You should never create files in this directory yourself. To get or set preference values, you should always use the NSUserDefaults class or an equivalent system-provided interface." as I mentioned on daviesgeek's answer.

Answer (score 12):

I had this happen and I fixed the problem by relogging in to Google Sync.

The profile file is stored in:

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`

Usually an application will install data in `/Library/Preferences/` and/or `~/Library/Preferences/`.

Data can also be placed after any of the following patterns:

`/Library/Preferences/<application name>/`

`~/Library/Preferences/<application name>/`

`/Library/Application Support/<application name>/`

`~/Library/Application Support/<application name>/`͏͏͏͏

`/Library/<application name>/`

`~/Library/<application name>/` ͏͏͏͏

Comment: Also, some random person said that [...Audio](https://archive.is/2yJ11#selection-1511.0-1511.15) folder may be too for audio apps.

Comment: Btw, what happens if an app itself is called Preferences and it tries to do `~/Library/<application name>/`? What's the **escape mechanism** used by mac? ¶
 Separately, what does `byhost` mean in `~/library/preferences`?

Comment: Apple has detailed information on this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/MacOSXDirectories/MacOSXDirectories.html

Comment: Is there an environment variable for that?

Comment: If the App is from the Mac AppStore it will be in `~/Library/Containers/<application name>/`

Comment: Data shouldn't be saved to these `Preferences` folders without using Apple's API. According to Apple's File System Programming Guide linked by @Bachsau, "Contains the user’s preferences. You should never create files in this directory yourself. To get or set preference values, you should always use the NSUserDefaults class or an equivalent system-provided interface."

Comment: @Poikilos Only the `Preferences` folder. Applications are free to place arbitrary data in `Application Support`. But when looking for saved data, it can often be found in any of the directories mentioned above, because of bad developers who don't care for standards. But if you're a developer yourself, you should consult official documentation, which also says one should use application IDs in reverse-domain format, like `com.bachsau.myapp` instead of the application's name for directory names. Also `~/Library/<application name>/` is not a valid path at all.